# Edit own activities created for visible contacts

Tags: activities, 4.7

We have a requirement to allow authenticated users to add activities to any contact in our system, while at the same time, not allowing them to edit the basic contact information about some of the contacts. By enabling the "View all activities (for visible contacts)" permission, and permissioning using ACLs to edit some contacts and view others, users are able to create activities. However, when viewing a submitted activity, they are unable to edit it (even though they entered it). Is there a simple way to allow users to edit the activities they created?

We're using Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 4.7.4